# Is there a server-side way to see if a person has already viewed a website?

Tags: php, database, cookies

I am currently working on an idea for a website which is built around the principle that when a user (who has to be logged in) first visits a website he or she will be shown some guidelines as an overlay on the main page. (Mainly some tooltips to buttons and sections to explain what they do or what they are.) When the user then clicks a button "I get it!" those messages will not show again on any visit.

Of course the first thing that comes to mind is setting a cookie. The problem with that is that the cookie is set locally. Id est, if a user clears his cache, history and cookies, the messages will pop up again. I am looking for a server-side way. Users will definitely have multiple devices. So making an extra table field for an IP won't be a good solution.

Ideally, I'd like a way that is linked to a user's account. So I'll be creating some pre-defined accounts for the people that can see the website, and when they first log in and the messages are shown to them, I'd like to "*bake* a server-side cookie", if you will, that remembers for the eternity that the user has already seen those messages.

(Extra points if you can also make it so that a user can click a button "Help?" which undoes the "server-side cookie" so that the messages are displayed again.)

I wish I could give you a "what have I tried", but I cannot. Some pointers to the direction I have to look in would be nice. (**Note**: I am a front-end webdev - see my rep - and I'm just starting in PHP, so be gentle and didactic please.)

Comment: why not just set it as a field in the database? assuming you're using a database for these pre defined accounts

Comment: If you let them log in, there's usually some data stored about those users somewhere? Set a flag on those users at creation to show the help, don't show the help for logged in users which don't have the flag, and reset the flag on the button click. It depends a bit on how your users are logged in, based on what data from which source.

Comment: @KaiQing Could you elaborate on this? (In an answer maybe?) As I said I'm relatively new to PHP and especially to databases.

Comment: @Wrikken That sounds good, but I have no idea what *a flag* is. I am an utter newb in SQL or what not. With this project I am trying to gain some knowledge on the subject. Learning by doing, I guess.

Comment: I don't know if I can succinctly explain database usage. First let's ask by what means were you creating these pre defined accounts? You can google search mysqli or PDO and use any reference from php.net to get started using either. Look into prepared statements for either mysqli or PDO to make sure you're not leaving yourself open to attacks.

Comment: @BramVanroy: with a flag, I mean just a variable containing a boolean. For instance, a tinyint field in a database containing 0 or 1.

Comment: @KaiQing That's what I'm most afraid of: security. The plan is to make a website for my family to post some stuff on (birthday wishes and the such). So I will manually create all the accounts. I suppose that a flag could work, as Wrikken suggested? I'll have to figure out how that works then, though.

Comment: He's talking about using a database as well. Either way you may want to either look up how to use mysqli or PDO, or just install wordpress and look into building a simple module that handles this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should already have a table in your database for login information (i.e. Username, password). Another field could be called 'got_it' with a default value of 0. This means the user has not clicked "Got It" and they should be presented the welcome message when they log in. If the value is 1, they have clicked "Got It" and will not be presented the welcome message. Using php, you can grab this information from the database and present the data with if then statements.